# How to report a bug for Google Drive/Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to report a few issues, but I'm not sure if this is the right place?
Is there a Google Drive/Google Docs bugtracker?

Answer (score 16):

This here is not the Google Bugtracker.

For Google Docs, check this page:

https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs

For Google Drive this one:

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs

On these pages are links to the known issues. If your stuff is not in there, you might want to go to the help forum linked on the pages and present the issues there:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive

If you are using google apps script, you can report google drive SDK issues here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: Reporting issues to Google has always been a nightmare.

Comment: The page for GD works, but it's not the place to report issues about the API or to request changes.  There doesn't seem to be links to any such page, either.  Does anybody know where the bug tracker for GD lives?

Comment: Looks like google drive questions are best asked on SO: https://developers.google.com/drive/support

Comment: The only way which I've found is to use Help menu in application (shets/docs etc). Currently for spreadsheets is: Help > Help Sheets Improve