# How can I normalize / asciify Unicode characters in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, unicode, google-sheets, formulas, re2

I'm trying to write a formula for Google Sheets which will convert Unicode characters with diacritics to their plain ASCII equivalents.

I see that [Google uses RE2](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) in its "REGEXREPLACE" function. And I see that [RE2 offers Unicode character classes](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).

I tried to write a formula (similar to [this one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ea4TGG-7Gs8)):

```
REGEXREPLACE("público","(\pL)\pM*","$1")
```

But Sheets produces the following error:

> Function REGEXREPLACE parameter 2 value "\pL" is not a valid regular expression.

I suppose I could write a formula consisting of a long set of nested SUBSTITUTE functions ([Like this one](https://gist.github.com/akora/51b2933a2554776d7144)), but that seems pretty awful.

Can any offer a suggestion for a better way to normalize Unicode letters with diacritical/accent marks in a Google Sheets formula?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[[:^alpha:]]` (negated ASCII character class) works fine for `REGEXEXTRACT` formula.

But `=REGEXREPLACE("público","([[:alpha:]])[[:^alpha:]]","$1")` gives "pblic" as a result. So, I guess, formula doesn't know what exact ASCII character must replace "ú".

---

**Workaround**

Let's take the word `públicē`; we need to replace two symbols in it. Put this word in cell A1, and this formula in cell B1:

```
=JOIN("",ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","$1-"),"-"),D:E,2,0),SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","$1-"),"-"))))
```

And then make directory of replacements in range D:E:

```
    D    E  
1   ú   u
2   ē   e
3  ...  ...
```

This formula is still ugly, but more useful because you can control your directory by adding more characters to the table.

---

**Or use Java Script**

Also [found a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123501/replacing-accented-characters-with-plain-ascii-ones), which works in google sheets.

Comment: After two years, I suppose I need to accept this solution, but honestly these workarounds are all still pretty ugly. Come on, Google, fix this!

Comment: Hi, @Kirkman14.[This text functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?visit_id=1-636546276795993789-3021020026&hl=en&rd=2) is all we have so far. The better solution would be writing a custom function or [reporting a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12106694/5372400) on google forum.

Answer (score 3):

This did it for me in Google Sheets, Google Apps Scripts, GAS

```
function normalizetext(text) {
    var weird = 'öüóőúéáàűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁÀŰÍçÇ!@£$%^&*()_+?/*."';
    var normalized = 'ouooueaauiOUOOUEAAUIcC                 ';
    var idoff = -1,new_text = '';
    var lentext = text.toString().length -1

    for (i = 0; i <= lentext; i++) {
        idoff = weird.search(text.charAt(i));
        if (idoff == -1) {
            new_text = new_text + text.charAt(i);
        } else {
           new_text = new_text + normalized.charAt(idoff);
        }
    }

    return new_text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't require a Google App Script, and it's still fast, and relatively simple. It builds on [Max's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5372400/max-makhrov) answer by providing a full lookup table, and it also allows for case-sensitive transliteration (normally VLOOKUP is NOT case-sensitive).

Here is a link to the [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dwZqYXGCXz3t1Y9HwlQxR3qtw9Na4ji1Nz5sesA42iE) if you want to jump right into it. If you want to use your own sheet, you'll need to copy the TRANS_TABLE sheet into your Spreadsheet.

In the code snippet below, the source cell is `A2`, so you'd place this formula in any column on row 2. Using [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) AND [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136), we split apart the string in `A2` into an array of characters, then USING [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en), we do the following to EACH character in the array: First, the character is converted to its '[decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)' [CODE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094122) equivalent, then matched against a table on the `TRANS_TABLE` sheet by that number, then using [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en), a character X number of columns over (the index value provided) on the TRANS_TABLE sheet (in this case, the 3rd column over) is returned. When all characters in the array have been transliterated, we finally [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077) the array of characters back into a single string. *I provided examples with [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) as well.*

```
=iferror(
join(
  "",
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    vlookup(
      code(split(REGEXREPLACE($A2,"(.)", "$1;"),";",TRUE)),
      TRANS_TABLE!$A$5:$F,3
    )
  )
)
,)
```

You'll note on the TRANS_TABLE sheet I made, I created 4 different transliteration columns, which makes it easy to have a column for each of your transliteration needs. To reference the column, just use a different index number in the VLOOKUP. Each column is simply a replacement character column. In some cases, you don't want any conversion made (A -> A or 3 -> 3), so you just copy the same character from the source Glyph column. Where you DO want to convert characters, you type in whatever character you want replaced (ñ -> n etc). If you want a character removed altogether, you leave the cell blank (? -> ''). You can see examples of the transliteration output on the data sheet in which I created 4 different transliteration columns (A-D) referencing each of the Transliteration tables from the TRANS_TABLE sheet for different use case scenarios.

I hope this finally answers your question in a fashion that isn't so "ugly." Cheers.

Comment: Worked really well.  One suggestion, in the TRANS_TABLE sheet, if you could update the formulas there to use TRANS_TABLE!TRANS_TABLE and TRANS_TABLE!TRANS_A, then the formulas would work if someone copies your sheet to their sheet, then copies the cell formula to their cell.

Comment: I see how that's confusing...I used "Named Ranges" in the first four columns. Instead, I split the named range version into a separate sheet.