# QUERY in combination with IMPORTRANGE sorts accented values incorrectly

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

As stated in the title, suppose I have `spreadsheet` with following values:

```
B
C
A
Š
Ť
Á
```

I then import the values from this spreadsheet using `QUERY` and `IMPORTRANGE` to different `spreadsheet`, exact function:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("<spreadsheet_id>"; "List 1!A:B"); "SELECT * WHERE Col1!='' ORDER BY Col1";-1)
```

The result I get is this:

```
A
B
C
Á
Š
Ť
```

So the `ORDER BY` works on separately on the non-accented letters and on the accented ones but not together, the result I expect is:

```
A
Á
B
C    
Š
Ť
```

This makes it useless for me. When I try to order them manually the data gets distorted (move to completely different rows, the ordering is not correct either. I've check, that the language in the settings is set correctly.

When I've googled a little, some links addressing different SQL (like MySQL) `COLLATE UNICODE`, but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to have a table to convert all accented characters to normal characters. As of now, `ORDER BY` is working as intended.  The code for your characters  `A
B
C
Á
Š
Ť` are `65
66
67
193
352
356`   Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651656

Comment: Thanks, but that sounds like a too much work, when you consider the fact, that the regular ordering of the data works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `query` invokes a completely different language that doesn't necessarily behave like other Sheets functions such as  `sort`. Since `sort` does what you want, use it instead of `order by` in query:

```
=SORT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(...); "SELECT * WHERE Col1!=''); 1; True)
```

sorts the output of query by the first column (1), ascending (True).  The output is

```
A
Á
B
C
Š
Ť
```

Comment: Great, I feel surprised I did not stumble upon this myself, considering how much time I've spent on it. Probably got to into the `ORDER BY` solution. Thanks.

Comment: And with headers?