# "Save to drive" permissions windows isn't mobile friendly

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm implementing the "Save to drive" widget(https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive) in a webpage, but when testing it from a mobile device, the permission page is shown in deskop format, with no proper style for those screens:

[image]

Is there any workaround for this or special/hidden parameter to avoid this?

(PS: It would be great from google guys to tweak the styles of the page to be more "mobile friendly" :P)

Comment: That is a webpage on Googles server I don't think they are going to let you change it.

Comment: @DaImTo I put the question for google drive team because of this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106497/how-to-report-a-bug-for-google-drive-google-docs

Comment: Voting to close this question as off topic Stackoverflow is not Google Drive support. Author should contact Google or add a feature request.

Comment: @DaImTo I've edited the question to be more SO oriented. Meanwhile I'll try to report that to google and link any updates here.